# An unbounded operator is closed if and only if its kernel is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Let $T : \operatorname{dom}(A) \subseteq X \rightarrow Y$ be an unbounded operator from a Hilbert space $X$ into another Hilbert space $Y$.

If $T$ is closed, then the kernel of $T$ is closed. Under which condition does the reverse implication hold?

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to construct an unbounded operator with $\mathcal{N}(T)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Of course, the scales fall from my eyes.